# How can I split DataFrame (pandas) on pages with django paginator?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-pagination

It is easy for `Series`. I just pass it to `paginator`. But, when I use `DataFrame`, it is call "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous". Maybe, there are problem with `count` method, but I don't know how I can change it. In my project `DataFrame` must be split on pages by rows.

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 1)  # Show 1 row per page

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    contacts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    contacts = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'list.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to segregate your columns and then use pagination on each column and then append them together, since dataframe iterates on columns. Basically by separating each column, you give the chance to iterator to go through the rows:

contact_list = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))

paginator1 = Paginator(contact_list['col1'], 1)

paginator2 = Paginator(contact_list['col2'], 1)

Comment: A better solution is:                                                                                          
paginator = Paginator(df.apply(lambda df: df.values,axis=1),num_of_items)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be caused by the fact that by `DataFrame.__iter__` iterates by column rather than row. You could call `df.iterrows()` or `df.values` if you want to get an iterator of your dataframe rows.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following code with my own dataframes and it works. Just convert your dataframe to a list of dicts and the paginator should just work fine.
Sorry for the late response I just came up with this question

> ```
> records = df.to_dict(orient='records')
>
> paginator = Paginator(records, num_of_items)
> page = request.GET.get('page')
> records = paginator.get_page(page)
> return render(request, 'list.html', {'contacts': records})
> ```